# Error: Expected a value of type 'List<String>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I get a json response from a server that looks like this:

```
{"status": "OK", "names": ["omegaChannel"]}
```

And then I parse it like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

The 'names' field of this map is a list of strings, so I want to convert it to a list of strings:

```
List<String> channels = map['names'];
```

No problem at compile time, but when the app reaches this line at runtime, I get this error:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'List<String>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>
```

I have tried the following solutions but to no avail. They all get the error.

Using .map() and .toString():

```
List<String> channels = map['names'].map((val) => val.toString()).toList();
```

Casting to a list of strings:

```
List<String> channels = map['names'] as List<String>;
```

Or even just using a plain list first:

```
List channels4 = map['names'] as List<String>;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest solution is:

```dart
List<String> channels = map['names']!.cast<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.from` to get list from map.

```dart
final List<String> names =  List<String>.from(map['names'] as List);
```

Make sure to get list while using `map['names']`.

Comment: Thank you it works. But I don't understand the last sentence of your answer. What do you mean by "get list"?

Comment: you need to make sure `map['names']` returns list from your data(map).